# Esp8266 V12 Wiring

Tags: arduino-ide, pins, hardware, esp8266

I have tried a Google search and cannot find any place that tells me exactly how to wire the version 12 esp8266 ,

How should it be wired for normal operation and for flashing ?

I am designing a diy pcb and need to know the specifics,to wire a switch for flashing purposes etc.I am using just a esp8266 version 12 standalone without a typical arduino micro-controller attached and will be flashing it to take the arduino ide ,any help with this would be great as I'm sure someone has already come across this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the [solution](http://www.instructables.com/id/Getting-Started-with-the-ESP8266-ESP-12/?ALLSTEPS#step3), on the first hit for googling "ESP8266 ESP-12".

> [image: wiring]
>
> You need to connect a few GPIO pins on the ESP-12 to 3.3V or Ground,
>   to set it in the right mode for communicating with it. Here are the
>   connections you need to make :
>
> VCC ----> 3.3V Power supply (Vout of LM1117)
>
> GND ----> Ground of power supply
>
> CH_PD ----> HIGH (3.3V)
>
> GPIO2 ----> HIGH (3.3V)
>
> GPIO15 ----> LOW (GND)
>
> GPIO0 ----> HIGH or Floating for AT Mode (3.3V) [ * if you want to
>   flash completely different firmware then you must connect it to ground
>   ]

You need to connect `GPIO0` to `GND` for flashing and to `VCC` for normal operation.

Comment: Thank you ,i wasn't sure where to believe as their seemed to be conflicting information but this could be due to different configurations,thank you for answering my question at least i can be sure now.Thank you